# Number change every 24 hours

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

I would like to provide a list of about 40 positive numbers and then have my home page display the first number.  Then at midnight, the number will change to the next number in the list.  When at the end of the list, the rotation starts over.  So for instance, a user goes to my page several times today and sees the first number in the list.  Then say 1:00am, they go back to the page and see the next number on the list and will do so until midnight tomorrow night...etc etc etc  Is this possible?

I've tried several different javascripts that does change the number according to my list BUT when a user goes to the page, it starts the list over again.

I am so new to this, I don't know which part of my code you might need since what I have been trying does what its supposed to do...just not how I want it to do.

Do I make sense?

Unfortunately, I won't be able to use php for this webpage.

Comment: You need to store what number you are up to. For every user, you need to do it backend. For single users, you need to store a cookie (or localstorage)

Comment: You need something which has a longer persistence state than javascript. A server side technology will be better suited to this, preferably in conjunction with a database of some sort.

Comment: You want random numbers or to use a list of certain numbers? I guess you could use a array that uses today's date to create a list of numbers that will be the same for all users until next day.

Comment: You need some kind of pointer. depending on the security that is needed, this pointer could be stored in a txt-file, xml-file, or in a database.

Comment: If the number is the same for every user you can do some maths with the time.

Comment: Thank you for all the quick responses!  I will take what you've offered and see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Define a start date (preferably in the past), calculate today's date, subtract the two, and then use modulo to squeeze it into the range of numbers you want to show:

```
var minDate = 15681, // days since 1-1-1970
nowDate = Math.ceil(new Date().getTime() / 1000 / 86400),
numbers = [1, 5, 1234, 6543, 1236456];

// get the number for today
console.log(numbers[(nowDate - minDate) % numbers.length]);
```

If the start date doesn't matter, you can simplify the expression to:

```
 numbers[Math.ceil(new Date().getTime() / 86400000) % numbers.length];
```

Btw, this won't change at midnight for everyone btw, because `.getTime()` gives GMT time.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I will try this out and get back with what worked for me.

Comment: After studying the code above, I am almost clear on how it works.  So then I wanted to try a test.  I copied the code, pasted into the head section of my document.  But I am confused on what I need to put into the body of the document where I want the number to display.  

I would paste some code but I can't figure out how to isolate it so it will display properly.  If you haven't guesses, I am a REAL newbie!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `new Date().getTime()` to get the current time in milliseconds. If you convert that to days, and round down, you can find the number of days since the epoch. Take the modulo of that and use it to obtain the index of your array of numbers. Since you're always using the current time (according to the user), you don't need to store any cookies or server-side counter.

```
var nums = [1,1,2,3,5,8,13]; // and so on
    d = new Date(), // today
    days = d.getTime() / (1000*60*60*24), 
    idx = Math.floor(days) % nums.length;
alert(nums[idx]); // should change once a day
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I am off now to try it out.